# Finding and adding lines to a RichTextBox

Tags: .net, vb.net

Right now I have three checkboxes (`chkBox1`, `chkBox2`, and `chkBoxMisc`) that finds a line and adds text to my Rich Text Box (`txtBox`).

Following code is `chkBox1` that checks to see if `"Text Here 1"` exists, and if so, delete it. Check to see if `"Text Here 2"` exists, if so, delete it. Add both again. Like so:

```
Private Sub chkBox1_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles chkBox1.CheckedChanged
'Find if "Text Here 1" exists. If so, delete it, since we're going to be adding it again.
        Dim text = ""
        Dim startindex = 0
        Dim endindex = 0
        For i As Integer = 0 To txtBox.Lines.Length - 1
            text = txtBox.Lines(i)
            If text.Contains("Text Here 1") = True Then
                startindex = txtBox.GetFirstCharIndexFromLine(i)
                endindex = text.Length
                txtBox.[Select](startindex, endindex)
                txtBox.Text = txtBox.Text.Replace(txtBox.SelectedText, String.Empty)
            End If
        Next

'Find if "Text Here 2" exists. If so, delete it, since we're going to be adding it again.
    For i As Integer = 0 To txtBox.Lines.Length - 1
            text = txtBox.Lines(i)
            If text.Contains("Text Here 2") = True Then
                startindex = txtBox.GetFirstCharIndexFromLine(i)
                endindex = text.Length
                txtBox.[Select](startindex, endindex)
                txtBox.Text = txtBox.Text.Replace(txtBox.SelectedText, String.Empty)
            End If
        Next

'if chkBox1 is checked, then add "Text Here 1"
        If chkBox1.Checked = True Then
            txtBox.Text = "Text Here 1" & vbNewLine & txtBox.Text & vbNewLine

'Search for "Text Here 1" and add "Text Here 2" right after it
            Dim Search As String = txtBox.Text
            Dim SearchResult As Integer = 0
            If Search.Contains("Text Here 1") Then
                SearchResult = SearchResult + 1
            End If

            Dim lines As List(Of String) = txtBox.Lines.ToList()
            Dim index As Integer = lines.FindIndex(Function(line) line.Contains("Text Here 1")) + SearchResult

            If index > -1 Then
                If chkBoxMisc.Checked = False Then
                    lines.Insert(index, vbNewLine & "TextBox 2 - Misc Off")
                Else
                    lines.Insert(index, vbNewLine & "TextBox 2 - Misc On")
                End If
            End If

            txtBox.Lines = lines.ToArray()


        End If
        Me.txtBox.Lines = Me.txtBox.Text.Split(New Char() {ControlChars.Lf}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
    End Sub
```

And here's my code for `chkBox2` which is supposed to determine whether or not `"Text Here 1"` and `"Text Here 2" (- Misc Off/On)` exists and add `"Text Here 3"` after `"Text Here 1"` if `"Text Here 2"` doesn't exist, and after `"Text Here 2"` if it does exist.

```
Private Sub chkBox2_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles chkBox2.CheckedChanged
'Find if "Text Here 1" exists. If so, delete it, since we're going to be adding it again.
        Dim text = ""
        Dim startindex = 0
        Dim endindex = 0
        For i As Integer = 0 To txtBox.Lines.Length - 1
            text = txtBox.Lines(i)
            If text.Contains("Text Here 1") = True Then
                startindex = txtBox.GetFirstCharIndexFromLine(i)
                endindex = text.Length
                txtBox.[Select](startindex, endindex)
                txtBox.Text = txtBox.Text.Replace(txtBox.SelectedText, String.Empty)
            End If
        Next

'Find if "Text Here 3" exists. If so, delete it, since we're going to be adding it again.
        For i As Integer = 0 To txtBox.Lines.Length - 1
            text = txtBox.Lines(i)
            If text.Contains("Text Here 3") = True Then
                startindex = txtBox.GetFirstCharIndexFromLine(i)
                endindex = text.Length
                txtBox.[Select](startindex, endindex)
                txtBox.Text = txtBox.Text.Replace(txtBox.SelectedText, String.Empty)
            End If
        Next

'if chkBox2 is checked, then add "Text Here 1"
        If chkBox2.Checked = True Then
            txtBox.Text = "Text Here 1" & vbNewLine & txtBox.Text & vbNewLine

'Search for "Text Here 1"
            Dim Search As String = txtBox.Text
            Dim SearchResult As Integer = 0
            If Search.Contains("Text Here 1") Then
                SearchResult = SearchResult + 1
            End If

'Search for "Text Here 2"
            If Search.Contains("Text Here 2") Then
                SearchResult = SearchResult + 1
            End If

            Dim lines As List(Of String) = txtBox.Lines.ToList()
            Dim index As Integer = lines.FindIndex(Function(line) line.Contains("Text Here 1")) + SearchResult

            If index > -1 Then
                If chkBoxMisc.Checked = False Then
                    lines.Insert(index, vbNewLine & "TextBox 3 - Misc Off")
                Else
                    lines.Insert(index, vbNewLine & "TextBox 3 - Misc On")
                End If
            End If

            txtBox.Lines = lines.ToArray()


        End If
        Me.txtBox.Lines = Me.txtBox.Text.Split(New Char() {ControlChars.Lf}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
    End Sub
```

So this should be the result:

> **If chkBox1 is checked then:**
>
>   Text Here 1
>   Text Here 2
>   This works!
>
> **If chkBox2 is checked then:**
>
>   Text Here 1
>   Text Here 3
>   This doesn't work!
>   **Actual result:**
>
>   Text Here 1
>
> **If chkBox1 is checked and chkbox2 is checked then:**
>
>   Text Here 1
>   Text Here 2
>   Text Here 3
>   This doesn't work!
>   **Actual result:**
>
>   Text Here 1
>   Text Here 2

Does anyone see what I'm missing here?

Comment: Once you call `txtBox.Text = txtBox.Text.Replace(...)` it will replace **all occurrences** in the _**entire**_ text box, not just the current line. Thus selecting the line won't do anything since you're not typing anything new (such as a backspace), only replacing parts of the text.

Comment: Also, what on earth do you have this for: `Me.txtBox.Lines = Me.txtBox.Text.Split(New Char() {ControlChars.Lf}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)`?? You're extracting the lines only to add them again... It's similar to doing: `txtBox.Text = txtBox.Text`.

Comment: If your desired output is what you have in your blockquote there, then your code is extremely overly complicated. I would rethink the design from scratch. For instance, the loop `For i As Integer = 0 To txtBox.Lines.Length - 1` is used 4 identical times, but you could just wrap it in a function call. And there is a lot of redundancy in what you're doing. For instance this line `txtBox.Text = "Text Here 1" & vbNewLine & txtBox.Text & vbNewLine` could also include `"Text Here 2"` right after it, instead of searching for where you put it then adding it right after it.